# Sims Medieval refuses to open

Tags: sims-medieval

I am using a windows 10 laptop and whenever i try to open sims medieval it just crashes. Has anyone else experienced this problem and do you have a solution?I am using a disk version and my specs are enough to run it.

Comment: Does it just crash to desktop, or do you get an error message too? also, are you using the disk version or a version downloaded from Origin?

Comment: please also indicate your config (minimal specs), and if your graphic card driver is up to date (by editing the question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, this is a very well-known problem happening on Windows 10 PC, running the disk version of the game. As stated on [this thread on The Sims forums](https://forums.thesims.com/en_US/discussion/877448/sims-medieval-and-windows-10), you should try to convert your game key to a digital version from Origin:

> I was having trouble running it on Win 10, too. I went into Origin and
>   put in my product code and was able to convert them to a digital
>   download. They run perfectly.

How to do this:

> Go into Origin and under the Origin menu at the top, click on "Redeem
>   Product Code". You enter the code from your physical copy there and it
>   will turn it into a digital copy.

[EA Community Manager](https://answers.ea.com/t5/Other-The-Sims-Games/Sims-Medieval-won-t-launch-on-Windows-10/td-p/5664630) advises to uninstall any version of the game before downloading and installing the digital version from Origin:

> Please, try this:
>
> - Uninstall both the disc and downloaded versions of the game.
> - Use Ccleaner to clean your registry.
> - Restart your computer
> - Install the game again through Origin.